# Force close message for every single application on Easypad Junior

Tags: force-close

I have an Easypad Junior and have the following problem with it: When I start it and unlock it i get this error:

> The application <..., it does that for every single one> has stopped
>   unexpectedly

The only thing I can do is to press <kbd>Force close</kbd> and then I enter a loop of pressing that. That leads nowhere. In safe mode, the same story.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please try to improve the
quality of your question. [Some good hints how to ask questions can be
found on here](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/a/1182/). This
will also increase your chances to get a good answer.

Comment: Sounds like a so-called "force-close-loop". Have you checked with the [force-close tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/force-close/info)? It's described there, and some first-aid pointed out (you always reach the corresponding wiki for a tag by clicking the tag, and selecting the "info" tab, by the way, and it quite often holds some first-aid information). But as in your case the problem persists even in safe-mode, you might need to factory-reset the device :(

Comment: But the question is .. how do i enter recovery mode to do the factory reset? I can't find anything online about that..

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of permission issue.
If you are rooted and installed Custom Recovery(CWM recovery,TWRP Recovery) there is an option in `advanced`.

1: Boot into recovery
2: Advanced (CWM Recovery)
3: Fix permissions

It will fix permissions for all apps installed.
try it.. or else provide more details like ROM,Root status,recovery etc.

Comment: It's not rooted.. and i can't manage to enter recovery mode. I can't find anywhere the combination of keys i have to press.. and in safe mode i get the same error.. But thanks for your answer